# Using getSelected() method of StandardSetController class

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, help

I am new to salesforce. My purpose is to display all the values of the selected checkboxes on one page, to the pther VF page. I studied that this can be done by getSelected() method. But I am unable to use it.
Please can someone explain me with an example of VF page.

Is there any other method to achieve this goal?

Comment: Once you getSelected() you need to pass it to the controller to assemble a collection to send to the next page. The controller then creates a new pagereference passing the collection to the new page, especially when you're able to use the same controller. See the [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm) and [Visualforce in Practice](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf).

Comment: Can you plese help me with an example, as I am new to programming

Comment: @crmprogdev How do you get the view `PageReference` from a `StandardSetController`? I only see `cancel` and `save` as returning a `PageReference` and it's just to the redirect or home page.

Comment: @AdrianLarson. In the appendix of the VF Developer Guide you'll find the [getSelected() method for standardSetControllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_getSelected.htm). It returns a list of the sObjects that have been selected.

Comment: @crmprogdev But that does not allow you to get some sort of redirect to a page using those records, which the OP seems to be looking for.

Comment: At the time I commented, I thought he was asking how to create an action method in the controller to use the selection to create the redirect. The list that's returned would be what he'd need. Without a custom action method, since it returns a list of sobjects, he might be able to use $Action (list) but the redirect would again seem to be an issue. He'd seem to need $Page and a means to parse the list. So I don't have an answer. If I'd had one, I'd have posted it as an answer instead of as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In custom button you can write something like this:

```
    // Assuming you have standardcontroller for Case object
    var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Case)};

    var updateRecords = [];

    if (records[0] == null) {
        alert("Please select at least one Case to update.");
    } else {
        window.location = 'apex/MyVisualforcePage?recs='+records.join(',');
    }
```

After that you can get all selected record from the parameter named `recs`like that and do whatever you want:

```
List<String> caseIds = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recs').split(',');
```

Comment: But where have you used "StandardSetController class" and getSelected method?